# Django and nginx and gunicorn and docker compose - configuring URLs

Tags: django, nginx, static, docker-compose, nltk

I'm building a practice app in Django 2, Docker Compose and Nginx. Spinning up the images is successful, however, any non Django/Python files **do not** load.

For example, /static/bootstrap-3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.css (or any file in /static) does not load. I've seen a few other related questions on SO about this, but for some reason I think I'm still missing something for my config. There are console logs and terminal lines indicating 404 errors for the static or other directory resources.

Appreciate any help, thanks!

**WorkDir Tree**

```
|- gunicorn/
|- nginx\
|-- nginx.conf
|-- ...
|- django/
|-- __init__.py
|-- templates/
|-- static/
|-- manage.py
|-- settings.py
|-- forms.py
|-- views.py
|-- urls.py
|-- wsgi.py 
|- docker-compose.yml
|- Dockerfile
|- requirements.txt
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM python
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

ADD . /ljingo
WORKDIR /ljingo

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
RUN python -m nltk.downloader punkt
RUN python -m nltk.downloader wordnet
RUN python -m nltk.downloader averaged_perceptron_tagger
```

**requirements.txt**

```
Django==2.0
django-crispy-forms
psycopg2
gunicorn
nltk==3.3
```

**nginx/nginx.conf**

```
server {
    root /;

    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    access_log /logs/access.log;

    error_log /logs/error.log;

    location /media  {
        alias /django/media;
    }

    location /static {
        alias /django/static;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_pass http://django:8000;
    }
}
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '2'
services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - .:/ljingo
      - ./nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - ./static:/static
    depends_on:
      - django

  django:
    build: .
    image: ljingo
    command: python3 manage.py collectstatic
    command: python3 manage.py migrate
    # command: python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:80
    command: gunicorn ljingo.wsgi -c ./gunicorn/gunicorn.py -b 0.0.0.0:8000
    # depends_on:
    #   - db
    volumes:
      - .:/ljingo
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
```

**Terminal STDOUT output**

```
mac:django-gunicorn bmalone$ docker-compose up
django-gunicorn_django_1 is up-to-date
Starting django-gunicorn_nginx_1 ... done
Attaching to django-gunicorn_django_1, django-gunicorn_nginx_1
django_1  | [2018-08-01 00:23:22 +0000] [1] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.9.0
django_1  | [2018-08-01 00:23:22 +0000] [1] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8000 (1)
django_1  | [2018-08-01 00:23:22 +0000] [1] [INFO] Using worker: sync
django_1  | [2018-08-01 00:23:22 +0000] [9] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 9
django_1  | [2018-08-01 00:23:23 +0000] [10] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 10
django_1  | [2018-08-01 00:23:23 +0000] [11] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 11
django_1  | [2018-08-01 00:23:23 +0000] [12] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 12
django_1  | [2018-08-01 00:23:23 +0000] [13] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 13
django_1  | Not Found: /static/custom.css
django_1  | Not Found: /static/bootstrap-3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.css
django-gunicorn_nginx_1 exited with code 0
```

Comment: I think it's not finding the `.css` files in the your static assert directory `/static/`. Maybe try adding `COPY custom.css /static/custom.css` to your dockerfile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `docker-compose.yml` file cannot have more than one `command` entry. You need to combine the calls to `manage.py` and `gunicorn` into a single command.

```yaml
command: python3 manage.py collectstatic && python3 manage.py migrate && gunicorn ljingo.wsgi -c ./gunicorn/gunicorn.py -b 0.0.0.0:8000
```

Since this gets a bit long and hard to read, I recommend creating a simple bash script that runs each command, and is called from the `docker-compose.yml` configuration:

**start_django.sh**

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -ex

python3 manage.py collectstatic
python3 manage.py migrate
gunicorn ljingo.wsgi -c ./gunicorn/gunicorn.py -b 0.0.0.0:8000
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```yaml
django:
  # ...all of the other config goes here, but a single command entry...
  command: ./start_django.sh
```

Make sure that once you've created the `start_django.sh` you give it executable permissions inside the container. This can be done with your `Dockerfile`:

**Dockerfile**

```
ADD . /ljingo
RUN chmod +x /lingo/start_django.sh
WORKDIR /ljingo
```

Comment: Awesome!
This plus a single change in my nginx.conf file -- "location /static/" to "location ^/static/" -- and I can successfully deploy static files over nginx along with my Django app. Thanks @damon!

Comment: Another note - the chmod command did not run for my in my Python environment, but the COPY command in Docker apparently matches local permissions so after changing the +x perms locally the script executed okay.

Comment: @RoboBear – Re: Permissions » It's better if you don't rely on your local env's permissions. Are you sure your Dockerfile had the `RUN chmod ...` line after `COPY . /ljingo`? 

Glad I could help :)